# Como puedo matar un proceso por su nombre usando batch?

Tags: batch

Hola mi pregunta es simple como podría hacer usando batch para matar un proceso solamente por su nombre no por su pid o proceso id, solamente su nombre.
Tendría que usar taskkill /m y el proceso. pero en mi caso no me valdría el pid sino el nombre.

¿Cómo puedo hacer para matar el proceso solamente usando su nombre?

Si no fuera posible pues alguna otra alternativa posible en algun otro lenguaje.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes usar el comando `taskkill /IM nombre.exe /F (Si es necessario forzar)`.

`IM` es Image Name, puedes ver los `IM` usando el comando `tasklist`

Por ejemplo, abres un block de notas y escribes

```
taskkill /IM notepad.exe
```

Se te cerrará el bloc de notas y saldrá este mensaje :

```
CORRECTO: señal de terminación enviada al proceso "notepad.exe" con PID 12284.
```

Espero haberte solucionado el problema.

Answer (score 0):

**Usa esto**

```
taskkill /im "nombre.exe" /f >nul 2>nul
```

**/IM** se utiliza para el nombre.

**/F**  para forzar la detención.

**>nul**  para que el comando no tenga salida.

**2>nul**  para que el comando no tenga salida con errorlevel 2.